# After using search in firefox all the custom typography dissappears

Tags: wordpress, webkit, font-face

I came up with a strange problem. I am building this site: www.bellated.us.lt and after using search (let's say - http://www.bellated.us.lt/?s=nonews) all the custom typography (like font-faces and google webkits) disappear. This is only in firefox. Actually no idea where to start to look for the problem. Any ideas on this issue will be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because of invalid HTML. You have two opening  tag and no closing .
First correct the tags then check if it is still showing incorrectly in firefox.